# Safe for model method to rely on loaded model state?

Tags: database, model

Is it safe for a model method to rely on the model being in a loaded state i.e. accessing a data value?

An simplified example:

```
public function testMethod()
{
   return 100 x $this->getData('test_attribute');
}
```

This method only makes sense if the model had loaded correctly.

Is this bad practice? Or any alternative?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to test if a model was loaded is

```
$model->load(...);
if ($model->getId()) {
    // ... model loaded ...
}
```

Or, if you are in the context of the model class, use `if ($this->getId())` accordingly.

Comment: testMethod in my example is inside the model itself.  But it relies on data that will only be on the model after it is loaded correctly

Comment: In that case it is customary to use ```if ($this->getId())``` to check if the model was loaded correctly. Of course you can use any other attribute that you can rely on to have a value that evaluates to true in a boolean context, too.

Comment: Yea the syntax im fine with, its the concept behind it i was not sure about i.e. whether a model should have to check if it is loaded / has an id or if there is a more elegant / standard magento way to do this.  Now you have confirmed this is the way

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe. If a dependency is required, it should validate that dependency:

```
public function testMethod($product)
{
   if(!$product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product){
      Mage::throwException('/*meaningful exception*/');
   }
   return 100 x $product->getData('test_attribute');
}
```

Another way is type-hinting:

```
public function testMethod(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
```

Alternatively, if you're relying on properties set you should use a protected getter:

```
public function getTestAttribute(){
    if(!isset($this->_test_attribute)){
        // then load it
    }
    return $this->getData('test_attribute');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is standard **_afterLoad()** function you can use:

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    //you can set some model flag or fire some method here
    return parent::_afterLoad();
}
```

Comment: I prefer answer of @Vinai, but if you want to be sure 100%, try to use above